# VBA - Importing Data from Multiple Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am not looking for help with any specific vba coding, just peoples ideas on the best approach to handle a couple of scenarios. The solution has to work with Excel 2007 onwards (can not use Get & Transform / Power Query). In both cases the idea is to have a Master document in to which raw data is updated each week. It should not be necessary to manually redefine any of the formulas or references in the Master document after the update process in order to summarise / analyse the data.

**Scenario 1 :** Weekly sales figures for various products received from six different retail outlets in the form of an .xlsx file. The data is contained on one sheet in each file. Although the product lists are the same the layout of the data from each outlet is different and a 'standard' template will not be introduced. The user needs the ability to manually select each file to include in the update. The data from each outlet needs to be combined in the 'Master' document for additional processing etc.

What would be the best way to automate the Master document update process?

Possible idea :  in the Master spreadhseet create an MS Query for each outlet to import the data from each outlet in to separate sheets in the Master spreadsheet. For each outlet the user would be prompted to identify the file and its location using Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen) and the response used to modify the connection string prior to running the Query to retrieve the latest information.

**Scenario 2 :** Multiple workbooks received each week (80+) containing employee time and attendance data. The workbooks are saved in a single folder. The layout and format of the workbooks is the same with the data presented on one sheet in each. The data needs to be combined in the Master document for analysis.

What would be the best approach to allow the user to identify the workbooks and the transfer the data from these in to the Master spreadsheet for processing. Can not use the 'From Folder' in Get & Transform as it must work in Excel 2007 upwards.

Thanks

Comment: Scenatio 1 seems hardly possible given the layout differs per sheet. If you provide your sales people with an easy to use template chances are they'd actually use it and make your consolidation life a lot easier :-)

Comment: Scenario 1: show us some examples of different sheets, do they all contain the same info, just in a different format? Are the headers consistent? || Scenario 2: Use DIR to loop through all files in a folder, just create a folder per week and let user select that folder.

Comment: Unfortunately there is little consistency in the data files from each outlet for scenario 1 except that each file contains sales figures for the same items. The layout, column headings etc are different and a standard template will NOT be adopted (not my decision). Therefore I was thinking about creating separate queries (one for each outlet) to handle each of the data files. The user selects the file location for each outlet and the connection string is modified in the associate query before refreshing the query.

Answer (score -1):

What would be the best approach to allow the user to identify the workbooks and the transfer the data from these in to the Master spreadsheet for processing?  I think you need to hook into this AddIn, as described below, and all your questions will be answered.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

[image]